# android studio page blank

Tags: android, android-studio

when i open android studio everything is blank but before it used to show a mobile screen screen shot here http://postimg.org/gallery/ypphc3ni/

i thenewbosotn gaming tutorial said to download gdx after which all this is happening

i tried to reinstall still i have same prob

img 1 how it is looking 
img 2 how it was before

Comment: You probably changed some view settings for the project. Try double checking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get back to the UI editor:

1. Open "MyApplication" with the little triangle on the left
2. Open the "res" folder"
3. Open the layout folder
4. Click on activity_main.xml
5. Your UI should automatically load in

Comment and tell me if everything works. Hope this helped!

Comment: worked but getting error Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Comment: Either: A: You are not connected to the Internet. or B: You are connected, but your ISP/school/something is blocking connection to the Gradle Build Server. If you are on a computer that blocks this connection, you are doomed, but make sure your internet is working first.

Comment: if your connection IS blocked, ask your network admin to allow this site: [here is the link](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.7-rc-2-all.zip)         You can also try to go tho this site to see if it is blocked.

Comment: yes i m not able to go to that site i must contact them then

Comment: Yep! Ask them to unblock the site I commented. Tell me how it goes, and please mark the answer as correct! Thanks! Can't wait to see how it goes!